# addchildviewcontroller pass data

Tags: ios, xcode, parent-child

I'm trying to pass data to a childviewcontroller.
I have a view controller with two buttons and one view. Pressing the buttons defines the view that is shown.
The specific case is I want to show a list of items. The first way (button) is in a list, the second on a mapview. To show the items i need to pass a category to the child.

In my viewDidLoad I add both viewcontrollers with addchildviewcontroller en set my view to the view of the listviewcontroller.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    ItemListViewController * itemListViewController = (ItemListViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ItemList"];
    itemListViewController.view.frame = detailView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:itemListViewController];
    [itemListViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    itemListViewController.category = category;

    ItemListMapViewController * itemListMapViewController = (ItemListMapViewController *)[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ItemListMap"];
    itemListMapViewController.view.frame = detailView.bounds;
    [self addChildViewController:itemListMapViewController];
    itemListMapViewController.category = category;

    childControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:itemListViewController, itemListMapViewController, nil];

    [self.detailView addSubview:itemListViewController.view];
    currentPage = 0;
}
```

Acoording to the button pressed I change the my view

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender 
{   
    UIButton * button = sender;
    UIViewController *source = (UIViewController *)[childControllers objectAtIndex:currentPage];
    [source.view removeFromSuperview];
    UIViewController *destination = (UIViewController *)[childControllers objectAtIndex:button.tag - 100];
    [self.detailView addSubview:destination.view];
    currentPage = button.tag - 100;
    button = nil;
}
```

But passing the category to my childviewcontrollers does nothing. The category in my childcontrollers is always null.
I also tried to get the category by accessing the parentviewcontroller on the childviewcontroller,

```
NSLog(@"::%@", ((ItemListHeaderViewController *)self.parentViewController).category);
```

but this also results in null.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or maybe I'm understanding the whole containment story wrong... I'm new to ios development, so don't shoot me if the question is stupid. :) This is also my first question on stack overflow, so again don't shoot if I did something wrong.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
Kind regards...

Comment: How you declared the 'category' variable in your viewcontroller?

Comment: what is the property declaration for the `category` ? Is it (nonatomic, retain) ?

Answer (score 0):

In the child view controller .h:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *category;
```

Child VC .m:

```
@synthesize category;
```

Then get a reference to that class in the parent class and set the property.  I wonder why you are doing this in code.  Laying this out in IB is soooo much easier and working with segues more straightforward to me.

Comment: This, then as ElJay says: destination.category = category;